# A C++ function to figure out whether one unsigned integer is bigger than another

Tags: c++

I was wondering if you guys could help me with a function I'm trying to make to determine whether an unsigned integer `a` is bigger than `b`.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <iostream>

bool is_bigger(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
// returns true is a is bigger than b; returns false otherwise
{

     for (int i = 0, j = sizeof(unsigned int) * CHAR_BIT; i < j; ++i)
     {
        int b1 = (a << i) & (1 << (j - i - 1));
        int b2 = (b << i) & (1 << (j - i - 1));
        if (b2 && !b1)
            return false;
     }
     return true;
}

int main()
{
     unsigned int A = 0; 
     unsigned int B = 5;
     std::cout << is_bigger(A, B);
}
```

For some reason this program outputs `true` when it should be outputting `false`. Maybe something is wrong about my logic? Does anyone know of a library I can download that might have a function that can check whether one integer is bigger than another?

Comment: Uhm, if I'm allowed to ask a stupid question: why not simply use `a > b`?

Comment: @leemes: There are times when having a function (which is to say `std::greater`, why write one) is good.  How do you make a function pointer to `a > b`?  It's a bit hard to say `&operator>`, because it's overloaded.

Comment: @BenVoigt Of course, but then you implement it as `a > b` *if you implement it*. (That was my point) And the hard part at getting a function pointer to `operator > (unsigned int, unsigned int)` isn't the fact that `operator >` is overloaded but the fact that that particular overload isn't implemented as such (since it's a primitive type). Otherwise you could "easily" get a pointer to it (with ugly casting).

Comment: @leemes: I maybe meant to reply to your comment on Soren's answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yeah there it fits better :) And then I have to agree, there are cases. But the question doesn't look like one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the fact that you can simply compare unsigned integers with `operator>`, that means `a > b`, let's focus on your logic.

Edit: There is still something wrong with my version, see [Daniel Frey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23255999/592323).

If I was to write a loop which iterates over the bits of an integer from the most to the least significant one, I'd better use right shifting such that the bit you want to look at is moved to the least significant bit. Then mask the result with a single `1`, like that:

```
for (int i = sizeof(unsigned int) * CHAR_BIT - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
   int b1 = (a >> i) & 1;
   int b2 = (b >> i) & 1;
   if (b2 && !b1)
       return false;
}
return true;
```

Note: Writing `sizeof(a)` instead of `sizeof(unsigned int)` is better since you can then simply change the type of `a` and `b` in the signature without worrying about the function body. Very useful if you make it a function template.

Comment: This does not work for `a=6` and `b=5`, see my answer for what is missing.

Comment: @DanielFrey Good spot; I don't want to copy your hint into my answer just that it's complete. I give you a +1 instead.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your logic (instead of just using `a>b`), you need this:

```
 for (int i = 0, j = sizeof(unsigned int) * CHAR_BIT; i < j; ++i)
 {
    int b1 = (a >> i) & 1;
    int b2 = (b >> i) & 1;
    if (b2 && !b1)
        return false;
    if (b1 && !b2)
        return true;
 }
 return false;
```

Note that you need to return **immediately** when `b1 && !b2` is given and that the result should be `false` when all bits are equal.

Answer (score 1):

There's a library <strike>function</strike> functor, and you don't even have to download it, because it's part of the C++ Standard Library that comes with your compiler.

[`std::greater<unsigned>()(a, b)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater)

Comment: Almost. `std::greater<unsigned>()(a, b)` ;)

Comment: @leemes: It's a functor type?  Ahh, so it is.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your function should look like this....

```
bool is_bigger(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
    return a > b;
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't be a function at all. (Not that it hurts...)

Comment: There may be other considerations, like polymorphic behavior which would mean that `is_bigger` should works for many types from `unsigned int` to `struct Elephant` --I prefer to define my operator overloading as functions and then call the functions in the operator definitions as it in my opinion makes for cleaner code

Answer (score 0):

You are shifting both the value and the mask you use to get a bit. You should shift one or the other, never both. Also, since the inputs are unsigned the results of the `&` should also be unsigned.

Comment: But I guess `(1 << ...)` is *signed*, isn't it? (It shouldn't, and thus be written as `(1u << ...)` afaik)

Comment: @leemes, right you are, to avoid all the pitfalls of the usual integer promotions.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, with minimal changes to the OP:

```
bool is_bigger(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
  for (int i = 0, j = sizeof(unsigned int) * CHAR_BIT; i < j; ++i)
  {
    unsigned int a1 = a & (1 << (j - i - 1));
    unsigned int b2 = b & (1 << (j - i - 1));
    if (a1 != b2)
    {
      return (a1 > b2);
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```